# Проверка на наличие значения в (PySimpleGUI) sg.Combo (Выпадающем списке)

Tags: python, pysimplegui

попробовал так

```
if values['-KProiz-'] == 0:
        sql = 'EXEC [dbo].[BazaMskFindProiz] @Tovar=?'
        params = values['-KProiz-']
        dbCursor.execute(sql, params)
        dbCursor.commit()
```

мне нужно узнать, выбрано в списке или нет значения

Comment: Что именно не работает? Какая-то ошибка или результат не соответствует ожиданиям?

Comment: @KlimenkoKirill  я хочу проверить значение на его наличие(есть/нет), попробовал через `None` не получилось. Вопрос - если не через `None`, то как?